# single "as" or double "as"

Tags: grammar

In terms of using "as". Are the first and the third sentences correct? Or should I just use the second and fourth one?

(1) he plays soccer well as(just like) his father used to.

(2) he plays soccer as well as his father used to.

(3) he is good as his father was.

(4) he is as good as his father was.

Comment: Put a comma after "as" in #1, then it's OK.  Same for #3.  (Of course the meaning is changed, as sulfuric suggests.)

Comment: @HotLicks Don't you mean _before_ "as"?

Comment: Thanks, I think you meant before?

Comment: Yep, before "as".  I got it as-backwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think 1 and 3 should really be used.

Sentence 3 may turn to an implication that since his father was good, he turned out to the same but that won't really match how other sentences are framed and may cause confusion.

I'd just say to use the original form.

I hope I helped.

Comment: Thanks, but are they grammatically wrong? 

what about: 

(1) bears were not very much influenced by this incident as other animals were. 

(2) bears were not influenced by this incident as much as other animals were

Comment: In your sentence (1) you would need to omit the "very much" but otherwise it is correct. However the meanings are different. Sentence (1) says that, unlike the other animals, the bears were not affected; sentence (2) means that the bears were affected less. This is the point, the first form is an absolute comparison, the second is a comparison of degree.

Comment: Ok, 
What do you think now ?

(1) he plays soccer as his father used to.

(2) he is just like his father.

(3) bears were not influenced by this incident as other animals were.

Otherwise, if I want to use an adjective or an adverb (e.g., good, much, and well) I should use another 'as'?